# "Single user copy" for image texture node in 2.92 missing?

Tags: node-editor

In 2.9 I can just click the number and it's done (now I can assign different color spaces to the texture) In 2.92: Firstly - I don't understand this terrible UI design decision with this annoying arrow and hidden icons. Anyway, can I make the same thing (Single user copy for an image texture) in 2.92? Is there a magic button for that somewhere or am I shamefully missing something?
Thank you.[image]

Comment: Hello, this version is still in Alpha, I'm sure it will be present when it is officially released.